# Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib

Tags: macos, homebrew, libpng

> Main error

```
Process failed:
 dyld[29269]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hanbing/opt/anaconda3/envs/brainreg/lib/python3.9/site-packages/brainreg/bin/nifty_reg/osX/reg_aladin
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (no such file)
```

> Tried  `brew install libpng $ brew update $ brew upgrade libpng` . None of them work.

> Laptop information:

- OS: macOS, M1 CPU
- Version: 12.0.1
- Hardware specs: 1 TB flash storage    and external
  2TB USB DISK
- Python version: 3.9

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like the libpng you are installing is for intel, you'll have to find an arm version or compile it yourself

Answer (score 1):

I guess you migrate from an Intel Mac to M1 Mac. After upgrade Mac version also can meet some libs error.

This is because brew install some libs maybe using compile source code as binary file, this file only works to specific platform.

Maybe you can reinstall it, `brew reinstall libpng`.